# Python attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

I have the following project directory. `scriptA.py` and `scriptB.py` are both separate micro-services, but share largely the same codebase.

```
myproject
  apps/
     models/
       db.py
       ModelA.py
       ModelB.py
     scriptA.py
     scriptB.py

  scripts/
    import.py

  requirements.text
  README.md
```

I can run `python apps/scriptA.py` and `python apps/scriptB.py` just fine. They both import `models/db` and `models/Model(A|b)` just fine.

However, when I run `python scripts/import.py`, which also tries to use `models/db`, I get the following: `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

In `scripts/import.py`, I'm using the following relative import:

```
from ..apps.models.db import setup_db

def main():
  print("Main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

`scripts` is separated from `apps`, because it just contains a bunch of scripts for importing data into my database. Whereas `apps` contains all the code to run my applications.

Comment: You ideally need to run a file at the root of your project, which could then do `from scripts.import import main; main()`

Comment: @Peter So in my root, I should have a new script `import.py`, that essentially calls the `main()` from `script/import.py`?

Comment: Yup basically, I don't really know the "best" solution for handling relative imports, but this way is pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

From your command, I assume you're in `myproject` directory while executing `python apps/scriptA.py`. In that case, in import.py use:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append('apps/models)

from db import setup_db

def main():
  print("Main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Then you should run it normally.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this does. Seeing that I'm executing `python scripts/import.py`, what is `apps/models` referring to?

Comment: It's a relative path to `apps/models`. I found a mistake in my answer, updated from `apps` to `myproject`

Comment: That does not work when I try it. It keeps complaining about the relative import. In my case I should be doing `sys.path.append("../")`? So that I can use `import apps.models`

Comment: It's like this: you are in `myproject` directory and execute `python scripts/import.py` then your import should be the above I posted. If you change to, say, `scripts` directory, execute `python imports.py` your import should be `sys.path.append('../apps/models)`.  You can try to change the relative path to absolute path also

Comment: The relative path in `sys.path.append` should be determined by the folder you are standing *when you execute python script*. If `myproject`  and you want to import all module of `apps` folder then `sys.path.append("apps")` then you can `import apps.models`

Comment: The reason is that: when executing the script, python will take your current position and pass that to the relative path, so if you are standing in `myproject`, `sys.path.append("apps")` means: `sys.path.append("/absolute/path/myproject/apps")`